# How to set orientation for AMCharts Stockchart to vertical

Tags: amcharts

I am playing around with AMCharts StockChart for a projcet I am working on.

I will like to change the orientation for the StockCharts to vertical:
i.e. the categoryAxis on the Left, and the Value Axis bottom - so the lines would show vertically instead of horizontal (as it is by default)

Does anybody know how to do this?

Basically, I want to take [This Horizontal Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLwx1.png) and turn it into [this vertical chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuh66.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stock charts can only be rotated at the panel level. You can set `rotate: true` directly in each panel or in `panelsSettings`:

```
panelsSettings: {
  rotate: true
}
```

You'll need to disable the global scrollbar and use a panel-level chartScrollbar as the global one doesn't get rotated.

```
panels: [{
  chartScrollbar: {},
  // ...
}],
chartScrollbarSettings: {
  enabled: false
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/687a49e79ec41dfcbd7e578afe3491da)